# Generating div and input tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to generate textFields dynamically, but as I am using material design-lite, I don't understand how to generate div class and input class attributes and label tags.

Here, is the code in HTML :

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" name="passengername">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Passenger Name :</label>
</div>
```

Did some searching and found the below script but have no idea how to generate label tags and class attribute for the tags:

```
function addFields(){
    var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
    for (i=0;i<number;i++){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("passengername " + (i+1)));
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}
```

The code generates text fields but doesn't have the design i applied in css because i did not generate class attribute using js.

Comment: You've already got `document.createElement('div')`, and you can't guess how to create `label` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a similar approach to generate `label` tags too , and for the `div` you can create a container `div` add the static class names to it and append your `input` and `label` to it.